# How to keep an active MIDI BLE connection between an Arduino NANO 33 BLE (nRF52) and an iPad

Tags: ios, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, midi, nrf52

I'm realizing a BLE MIDI controller for iPad using an Arduino Nano 33 BLE device. The following code is able to:

- make the device discoverable as a BLE MIDI peripheral
- establish a connection with a BLE MIDI central application

The connection is stable only with Android apps. **Each iOS app (eg Garageband, AUM, etc.) closes the connection immediately** (the led on the arduino board turns on and off in few seconds), but if the device constantly sends MIDI messages (look at the lines of code commented in the *loop()* function) the connection remains active forever; unfortunately the repeated sending of messages is not the purpose of the controller that I want to realize.

There are probably *specific configurations* of the BLE service or *polling actions* to be implemented to comply with the strict iOS standards, but I could not find any working solution or example for the **Nano 33 BLE** device that does not include sending notes in the *loop()* function.

```
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>

byte midiData[] = {0x80, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

// set up the MIDI service and MIDI message characteristic:
BLEService midiService("03B80E5A-EDE8-4B33-A751-6CE34EC4C700");
BLECharacteristic midiCharacteristic("7772E5DB-3868-4112-A1A9-F2669D106BF3",
                                     BLEWrite | BLEWriteWithoutResponse |
                                     BLENotify | BLERead, sizeof(midiData));
bool midi_connected = false;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize built in LED:
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  // Initialize BLE service:
  if (!BLE.begin()) {
    Serial.println("starting BLE failed!");
    while (true);
  }
  BLE.setLocalName("MBLE");
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(midiService);
  BLE.setEventHandler(BLEConnected, onConnected);
  BLE.setEventHandler(BLEDisconnected, onDisconnected);
  midiCharacteristic.setEventHandler(BLEWritten, onWritten);
  midiService.addCharacteristic(midiCharacteristic);
  BLE.addService(midiService);

  BLE.setConnectable(true);
  BLE.setAdvertisingInterval(32);
  BLE.setConnectionInterval(32, 64);
  BLE.advertise();
}

void loop() {
  BLEDevice central = BLE.central();
  if (central) {
//    midiCommand(0x90, 60, 127);
//    delay(250);
//    midiCommand(0x80, 60, 0);
//    delay(250);
  }
}

void onConnected(BLEDevice central) {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  midi_connected = true;
}

void onDisconnected(BLEDevice central) {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  midi_connected = false;
}

void onWritten(BLEDevice central, BLECharacteristic characteristic) {
  auto buffer = characteristic.value();
  auto length = characteristic.valueLength();

  if (length > 0)
  {
    // echo on the next midi channel
    midiCommand(buffer[2], buffer[3], buffer[4]);
  }
}

void midiCommand(byte cmd, byte data1, byte  data2) {
  midiData[2] = cmd;
  midiData[3] = data1;
  midiData[4] = data2;
  midiCharacteristic.setValue(midiData, sizeof(midiData));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (finally) found a solution by myself looking at the **MIDI BLE Specifications** provided by Apple that says

> The accessory shall request a connection interval of 15 ms or less. Apple recommends starting with a request
> for a connection interval of 11.25 ms and going to 15 ms if the connection request is rejected by the Apple
> product.
> Intervals higher than 15 ms are unsuitable for live playback situations.

and later

> Apple devices that support Bluetooth Low Energy MIDI will attempt to read the MIDI I/O characteristic after establishing a connection with the accessory.
> [...] The accessory shall respond to the initial MIDI I/O characteristic read with a packet that has no payload.

So I changed the connection interval in the *setup()* function

```
BLE.setConnectionInterval(9, 12);
```

and included few lines in connection event handler function

```
void onConnected(BLEDevice central) {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  midi_connected = true;
  midiCharacteristic.setValue(0);
}
```

That's it!